# Threading en el Problema de los Filósofos con C#

Tags: c#, hilos

Me han asignado resolver el problema de los filósofos con C# y la estructura propuesta por el profesor. El programa se ejecuta bien y todos comen, pero en la versión del profesor los filosofos intentan comer en bucle varias veces y en el mio comen una vez y se termina el proceso, sin que ninguno se quede sin acceder a su palillo. Le he enseñado el código al profesor y me dice que el problema es que no utilizo objetos como referencia en los Monitores.

Esto es lo que he escrito:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace filosofos
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int numFilosofos = 5;

            Filosofo[] filo = new Filosofo[5];
            filo[0] = new Filosofo(0, 0, numFilosofos - 1);
            for(int i = 1; i <numFilosofos; i++)
            {
                filo[i] = new Filosofo(i, i - 1, i);
            }

            var t1 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(filo[0].comer));
            var t2 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(filo[1].comer));
            var t3 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(filo[2].comer));
            var t4 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(filo[3].comer));
            var t5 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(filo[4].comer));

            t1.Start(filo[0]);
            t2.Start(filo[1]);
            t3.Start(filo[2]);
            t4.Start(filo[3]);
            t5.Start(filo[4]);
        }
    }

    class Filosofo
    {
        int indice;
        int palilloIzq;
        int palilloDrc;

        public Filosofo(int indice, int palilloIzq, int palilloDrc)
        {
            this.indice = indice;
            this.palilloIzq = palilloIzq;
            this.palilloDrc = palilloDrc;
        }

        public void comer(object param)
        {
            Object[] objetos = new Object[5];
            for (int i = 0; i < objetos.Length; i++)
            {
                objetos[i] = new Object();
            }
            Filosofo filo = (Filosofo)param;
            if (Monitor.TryEnter(objetos[filo.palilloIzq], 1000))
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Filosofo {0} coge el palillo izquierdo", indice);
                    if (Monitor.TryEnter(objetos[filo.palilloDrc], 1000))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("El filosofo {0} coge el palillo derecho", indice);
                            Console.WriteLine("El filosofo {0} está comiendo.", indice);

                        } finally
                        {
                            Monitor.Exit(objetos[filo.palilloDrc]);
                            Console.WriteLine("El filosofo {0} deja el palillo izquierdo", indice);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("El filósofo {0} está hambriento.", indice);
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    Monitor.Exit(objetos[filo.palilloIzq]);
                    Console.WriteLine("El filosofo {0} deja el palillo izquierdo", indice);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("El filósofo {0} está hambriento", indice);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Yo entiendo que estoy usando objetos en los monitores. El Array objetos está compuesto por objetos y solo utilizo enteros para señalar el elemento del array que necesita.

¿Se me escapa algo?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Me da la impresión de que tus objetos realmente no están bloqueando los tenedores porque si te fijas no son globales, de hecho si ejecutas el código ves los filosofos obtienen los tenedores cuando los tiene otro. Por otro lado inicializaría el 0 como filo[0] = new Filosofo(0,  numFilosofos - 1, 0);si lo escribes verás porqué.
Las trazas te pueden despistar también porque libera siempre el izquierdo aunque realmente estás liberando bien los 2.

```
using System;
```

using System.Threading;

namespace filosofos
{
    class Program
    {
        public static Filosofo[] filo = new Filosofo[5];
        public static object[] tenedores = new object[5];
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int numFilosofos = 5;
            for (int i = 0; i < numFilosofos; i++)
                tenedores[i] = new object();

```
        filo[0] = new Filosofo(0, numFilosofos - 1, 0);
        //filo[0] = new Filosofo(0, 0, numFilosofos - 1);
        for (int i = 1; i < numFilosofos; i++)
        {
            filo[i] = new Filosofo(i, i - 1, i);
        }

        var t1 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(filo[0].comer));
        var t2 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(filo[1].comer));
        var t3 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(filo[2].comer));
        var t4 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(filo[3].comer));
        var t5 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(filo[4].comer));

        t1.Start(filo[0]);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        t2.Start(filo[2]);
        t3.Start(filo[3]);
        t4.Start(filo[1]);
        t5.Start(filo[4]);
        var s = Console.ReadLine();
        while (s != "exit")
        {
            s = Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

class Filosofo
{
    int indice;
    int palilloIzq;
    int palilloDrc;

    public Filosofo(int indice, int palilloIzq, int palilloDrc)
    {
        this.indice = indice;
        this.palilloIzq = palilloIzq;
        this.palilloDrc = palilloDrc;
    }

    public void comer(object param)
    {
        Filosofo filoComer = (Filosofo)param;
        bool lockTaken = false;
        Monitor.TryEnter(Program.tenedores[filoComer.palilloIzq], 1000, ref lockTaken);
        if (lockTaken)
        {
            try
            {

                lockTaken = false;
                Console.WriteLine("{1} Filosofo {0} coge el palillo izquierdo {2} dcho {3}", indice, DateTime.Now, filoComer.palilloIzq, filoComer.palilloDrc);

                Monitor.TryEnter(Program.tenedores[filoComer.palilloDrc], 1000, ref lockTaken);

                if (lockTaken)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{1} El filosofo {0} coge el palillo derecho {2}", indice, DateTime.Now, filoComer.palilloDrc);
                        Console.WriteLine("{1} El filosofo {0} está comiendo.", indice, DateTime.Now);
                        //Thread.Sleep(1000);

                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        Monitor.Exit(Program.tenedores[filoComer.palilloDrc]);
                        Console.WriteLine("{1} El filosofo {0} deja el palillo derecho", indice, DateTime.Now);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{1} El filósofo {0} está hambriento.", indice, DateTime.Now);
                }

            }
            finally
            {
                Monitor.Exit(Program.tenedores[filoComer.palilloIzq]);
                Console.WriteLine("{1} El filosofo {0} deja el palillo izquierdo", indice, DateTime.Now);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{1} El filósofo {0} está hambriento", indice, DateTime.Now);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Buenas. Repasando tu código he visto que en mi versión en realidad cada instancia de filósofo tenía su propio array por lo que no servía de mucho. Haciéndolo global sí que tiene más sentido. Sin embargo cuando intento acceder al array usando Program.objetos[filo.palilloIzq] me dice "No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo object en int". Gracias por responder!

Comment: Lo he arreglado con un Convert. En principio creo que ya funciona bien. Muchas gracias!